# php ajax form submit ..nothing happens

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a PHP Ajax form that I'm trying to submit a Zendesk API call. Whenever I use the ajax part, in order to keep the user on the same page, it doesn't work. When I remove the `<script>` part, it works fine, but obviously redirects to `contact.php` from `contact.html` so I'm thinking the problem is in the Ajax part, not in the PHP part.

Here is my HTML form:

```
<html>
        <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div class="box_form">

        <form id="zFormer" method="POST" action="contact.php" name="former">
        <p>
        Your Name:<input type="text" value="James Duh" name="z_name">
        </p>
        <p>
        Your Email Address: <input type="text" value="duh@domain.com" name="z_requester">
        </p>
        <p>
        Subject: <input type="text" value="My Subject Here" name="z_subject">
        </p>
        <p>
        Description: <textarea name="z_description">My Description Here</textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submitter" name="submit">
        </p>
        </form>
        </div>

        <div class="success-message-subscribe"></div>
        <div class="error-message-subscribe"></div>


<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

$('.success-message-subscribe').hide();
$('.error-message-subscribe').hide();

    $('.box_form form').submit(function() {
        var postdata = $('.box_form form').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'contact.php',
            data: postdata,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json) {
                if(json.valid == 1) {
                    $('.box_form').hide();

                    $('.error-message-subscribe').hide();
                    $('.success-message-subscribe').hide();
                    $('.subscribe form').hide();
                    $('.success-message-subscribe').html(json.message);
                    $('.success-message-subscribe').fadeIn();
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

});
</script>

        </body>
        </html>
```

And the PHP Part:

You can probably ignore most of this since it works when I don't use the Ajax. Only the last few lines gives the response `$array['valid'] = 1;` which should then be catched by `if(json.valid == 1)` above.

```
<?php
        ( REMOVED API CALL CODE FROM ABOVE HERE )

        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 

        foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
            if(preg_match('/^z_/i',$key)){
                $arr[strip_tags($key)] = strip_tags($value);
            }
        }
        $create = json_encode(array('ticket' => array(

        'subject' => $arr['z_subject'], 
        'comment' => array( "body"=> $arr['z_description']), 
        'requester' => array('name' => $arr['z_name'], 
        'email' => $arr['z_requester'])

        )));

        $return = curlWrap("/tickets.json", $create, "POST");


        $array = array();
        $array['valid'] = 1;
        $array['message'] = 'Thank you!';
        echo json_encode($array);


  ?>
```

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: You might be more likely to get an answer if you strip out any irrelevant code.

Comment: Will do, you're right :)

Comment: use Firebug or developer tools to see how ajax call goes, or add an error callback in your ajax call to trace it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect your use of `contact.php` as a relative URL isn't resolving properly. Check your JavaScript console and you should see an error that shows the post failing. Change `contact.php` to `www.your_domain.com/contact.php` and it should work fine

Comment: Just got my hopes up and changes it to the full URL but it's not working either. This is so weird, I can't find out what's wrong! When I remove the script part, it works perfectly.

Comment: And what does the console say? If you use Firefox install firebug add on and it will report the error

Comment: In headers, it shows contact.php with "200OK 430ms". In Post it shows the parameters as I input them in the form. And Response and HTML is empty.

Comment: Hmm that is strange. Is contact.php at the same domain?

Comment: Yep. Same domain. Even the same folder.

Comment: So I guess your ajax is ok. Is there a value for `$_POST['submit']`?

Comment: Omg, you're totally right. I changed it to `if ($_POST) { ` and it's working!

Answer (score 1):

Replace *jQuery(document).ready(function() {* by

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

Secondly from Jquery documentation:

> Note: Only "successful controls" are serialized to the string. No
>   submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted
>   using a button. For a form element's value to be included in the
>   serialized string, the element must have a name attribute. Values from
>   checkboxes and radio buttons (inputs of type "radio" or "checkbox")
>   are included only if they are checked. Data from file select elements
>   is not serialized.

Therefore submit button won't serialize through jQuery.serialize() function.

A solution below:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.success-message-subscribe').hide();
$('.error-message-subscribe').hide();

    $('#submitter').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $myform = $(this).parent('form');
        $btnid = $(this).attr('name');
        $btnval = $(this).attr('value');
        var postdata = $myform.serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'contact.php',
            data: { "btnid" : $btnid, "btnval": $btnval, "form-data": $form.serialize() },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json) {
                if(json.valid == 1) {
                    $('.box_form').hide();

                    $('.error-message-subscribe').hide();
                    $('.success-message-subscribe').hide();
                    $('.subscribe form').hide();
                    $('.success-message-subscribe').html(json.message);
                    $('.success-message-subscribe').fadeIn();
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Did that but still nothing happens :(

Comment: You should change your PHP code to 

if (isset($_POST['btnid'])) { 

Or simply use your old code and remove the 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

Comment: Yep. I did that and now it's working. Thanks so much! :)