# Ajax submit doesn't submit anything

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28930624/php-ajax-form-submit-nothing-happens) post but didn't help me im afraid, at the moment I press submit and the page refreshes but nothing is actualy submitted with my ajax call... Can you guys see any error?

```
$('.formen').on('submit',function(e){
alert("TEST");
    e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST", 
                url: "booked.php", 
                data: $('.formen').serialize(),
                complete: function(data){
                    $('#namn, #epost').val('');    
                    },
                success: function(response){
                    alert("Complete!");
                }
        });
});
```

I tried to put an alert when the form is submitted but nothing happend

book.php

```
<form class = "formen" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="form-group">
       <label for="">Name</label>
       <input type="text" id = "namn" class="form-control" name="name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
       <label for="">Email</label>
       <input type="email" id = "epost"class="form-control" name="email">
  </div>
  <input type = 'hidden' name = "datum" id = "datum" value = "<?php echo $date; ?>">
  <input type = 'hidden' name = "room" id = "room" value = "<?php echo $room; ?>">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And yes the values are defined, I think the problem is my submit function. This is what shows in my url when i press submit .php?name=David&email=Test%40asdsa&datum=2020-05-28&room=1&submit=
What am I missing?
I get the form by clicking on a button which I aswell include with ajax:

```
$(document).on("click", '.boka', function() { 
$.ajax({
url:"book.php",
type:"POST",
data:{'date': $(this).data('date')},
success: function(data){
    $("#conf").html(data);
}
});

});
```

Comment: Ajax does the partial page update, whereas the HTML form by default doesn't, it calls the POST API by refreshing the page, you should use e,preventDefault() inside your on("submit") function to avoid this default behaviour

Comment: I still get the same refresh even if i use preventdeafault:(

Comment: thought     return false; did the same as preventdefault aswell

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? If the page refreshes without submitting the AJAX request, this does not look like a PHP problem

Comment: What kind of problem is it then?

Comment: I tried to alert after submit but nothing is happening

Comment: Found the issues, seems like the ajax call had to be in book.php

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `event` to your `submit` function and prevent the event from submitting the form which is its default functionality like this:

```
$('.formen').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  .... # your rest of the code
});
```

P.S. `$('#namn, #epost').val()` condition would only check if the value of `name` is present, if it does the form will get submitted even if the `email` value is `null`

Answer (score 0):

Your code lacks **document.ready()** function.

so this should alert TEST. and works

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.formen').on('submit',function(e){
alert("TEST");
    e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST", 
                url: "booked.php", 
                data: $('.formen').serialize(),
                complete: function(data){
                    $('#namn, #epost').val('');    
                    },
                success: function(response){
                    alert("Complete!");
                }
        });
});
});
```

or you can try another way.
1.) Remove the form elements

2.) Add loader div to show a text during submision

3.) Add result div to display data from server end

4.) add **formen** variable to class in a submit form

```
 <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){


    $('.formen').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

var name = $('#name').val();
var email = $('#email').val();
var datum = $('#datum').val();
var room = $('#room').val();

    atpos = email.indexOf("@");
    dotpos = email.lastIndexOf(".");
        if(name==""){

            alert('please Enter name');


        }

 else if(email==""){

            alert('please Enter Email');


        }


else  if (atpos < 1 || ( dotpos - atpos < 2 ))
    {
        alert("Please enter correct email Address")
        return false;
    }


else{

$('#loader').fadeIn(400).html('<br><span> Please Wait, Your Data is being Submitted</span>');
var datasend = "name="+ name + "&email=" + email + "&datum=" + datum + "&room=" + room;

        $.ajax({

            type:'POST',
            url:'booked.php',
            data:datasend,
                        crossDomain: true,
            cache:false,
            success:function(data){

                $('#name').val('');
                                $('#email').val('');
                $('#loader').hide();
                $('#result').fadeIn('slow').prepend(data);
alert('data submitted');

            }

        });

        }

    })

});


</script>

  <div class="form-group">
       <label for="">Name</label>
       <input type="text" id = "name" class="form-control" name="name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
       <label for="">Email</label>
       <input type="email" id = "email" class="form-control" name="email">
  </div>
  <input type = '' name = "datum" id = "datum" value = "">
  <input type = '' name = "room" id = "room" value = "">

<div id="loader"></div>
<div id="result"></div>
  <button class="formen btn btn-primary" type="submit"  name="submit">Submit</button>
```

**booked.php**

```
<?php
echo $name =$_POST['name'];
echo $email =$_POST['email'];
echo $datum =$_POST['datum'];
echo $room =$_POST['room'];

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.formen').on('submit',function(e){
        // preventDefault() method stops the default action of an element from happening.
        // https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST", 
                url: "booked.php", 
                data: $('.formen').serialize(),
                success: function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                    alert("Complete!");
                },
                error: function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                },
                complete: function(data){
                    $('.formen').get(0).reset();
                }
        });
    });
```

Comment: actually i did: 

**// preventDefault() method stops the default action of an element from happening.
// https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp**